# react-native-video crashes on Android when loading Video component

Tags: android, react-native, exoplayer, react-native-video

When attempting react-native run-android and trying to load a screen with a Video component, my app crashes with this error:

```
java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: Exception from call site #20 bootstrap method
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.SlidingPercentile.(SlidingPercentile.java:38)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultBandwidthMeter.(DefaultBandwidthMeter.java:263)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultBandwidthMeter.(DefaultBandwidthMeter.java:240)
at com.brentvatne.exoplayer.ReactExoplayerView.(ReactExoplayerView.java:85)
at com.brentvatne.exoplayer.ReactExoplayerViewManager.createViewInstance(ReactExoplayerViewManager.java:64)
at com.brentvatne.exoplayer.ReactExoplayerViewManager.createViewInstance(ReactExoplayerViewManager.java:22)
at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager.createView(ViewManager.java:42)
at com.facebook.react.uimanager.NativeViewHierarchyManager.createView(NativeViewHierarchyManager.java:260)
at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$CreateViewOperation.execute(UIViewOperationQueue.java:200)
at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$DispatchUIFrameCallback.dispatchPendingNonBatchedOperations(UIViewOperationQueue.java:1085)
at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$DispatchUIFrameCallback.doFrameGuarded(UIViewOperationQueue.java:1056)
at com.facebook.react.uimanager.GuardedFrameCallback.doFrame(GuardedFrameCallback.java:29)
at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ReactChoreographer$ReactChoreographerDispatcher.doFrame(ReactChoreographer.java:134)
at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ChoreographerCompat$FrameCallback$1.doFrame(ChoreographerCompat.java:105)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:947)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:693)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```